# Vertical space to a container or a navigation bar

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm building a view (with a .xib file) that is going to be displayed with or without navigation bar depending on whether I'm pushing it onto the views stack or showing modally. I put a UIImageView at the top and now I'd like to set a vertical top constraint but the only option I see is "Top Space to Container". The effect is that if I have a navigation bar present and the vertical spacing is set to for example 100, it's still 100 from a container not 100 from the navigation bar.

How to set this vertical spacing somehow conditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't solved the problem like yours with Interface Builder directly. In my code I created a property that is bound to the constraint in Interface Builder, like this

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint;
```

and then you can modify the `myConstraint.constant` or anything in .m to make it dynamic.

For reference: https://github.com/kcome/DualPDF/blob/master/DualPDF/KCContainerViewController.m

Comment: Works for me! Thank you, and still, I'm wondering if there's a fix for that using only Interface Builder.